# How to make managed packages available for users other than developer edition or sandbox

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, package

I have created a managed package. Right now it can only be installed if the user has Developer Edition or Sandbox accounts, How can i make it available for the professional or other accounts as well?

Answer (score 0):

Did you just create a beta managed package version?  Beta versions can only be installed in Developer Edition or Sandbox orgs.  If you want to install the package in a production org, you need to release a production version of the package.

However, be careful as creating a production version locks some of your package metadata in place.